# Material designs lite tooltip breaking when using translate3d

Tags: css, material-design, material-design-lite

I'm trying to use [MDL tooltips](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#tooltips-section) but they are failing to work as expected when using the `translate3d` property (which I use in some animations)

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/Lp3wco85/2/)

```
.container{
    position:absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100px, 0);
}
```

Comment: not getting what you want :(

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is due to how the tooltip position is dynamically calculated on hovering in `material.js`. Please see: **https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/mdl-1.x/src/tooltip/tooltip.js#L69**

When you add a `transform` styling to the `parent <div>` that got pass on to the `<div>` tooltip and mess up the tooltip position calculation.

My suggestion is change the `translate3d` styling to the inner `<div>` only so it will not affect the `tooltip <div>`.

Comment: The translate3d property is applied to the whole element where the tooltip is. My purpose is not just to move the tooltip but its whole container elements and all its children. 
It seems Boostrap tooltip does a much better job calculating these things!

Comment: Unfortunately so, that's the current limit of MDL. Thanks for putting up the issue in Github though.